# Ending chrome equivilant of plugin-helper

Tags: google-chrome, browser

If I want to end the plugin processes for chrome how can I do so? They are all named chrome.exe and I can't tell one process from the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrench -> Tools -> Task Manager (sometimes Shift-Escape).

Can see tabs, plugins and extensions, all named, and can sort by name, memory usage, CPU usage or network usage.